# Drupal 8: What are services?

Tags: drupal-8

Are services simply a way to share an instance of a class?

I have looked at the following documentation:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2133171

https://ffwagency.com/digital-strategies-blog/drupal-8-services-dependency-injection-and-decoupling-your-code

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a quick introduction & concept but with the links you have you should be able to fully understand the potential.

### Concept

The concept of services is to decouple reusable functionality and makes these services pluggable and replaceable by registering them with a service container.

Your application is full of useful objects: a "Mailer" object might help you send emails while another object might help you save things to the database. Almost everything that your app "does" is actually done by one of these objects.

These useful objects are called **services** and each service lives inside a very special object called the **service container**.

```
$entityManager = $container->get('entity_type.manager');
```

The **container** allows you to **centralize** the way objects are constructed. It makes your life easier, promotes a strong architecture and is super fast!

The Symfony 2 documentation has a [great introduction to services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

### Usage

You can also organize your own code into services. For example, suppose you need to show your users a random, happy message. If you put this code in a **controller** or a **block**, **it can't be re-used**. Instead, you can create you own service.

---

You can find all the service that Drupal 8 expose on this documentation page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/services.

---

With all the links below & the introduction upper, you have everything to well understand & start using services:

- [Services and dependency injection in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2133171)
- [Drupal 8 Services, Dependency Injection, and Decoupling Your Code](https://ffwagency.com/digital-strategies-blog/drupal-8-services-dependency-injection-and-decoupling-your-code)
- [Structure of a service file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/structure-of-a-service-file)
- [Collection of documentation about Servie in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection)

---

I wish you all the best using Drupal 8 !